# Не удаётся внести данные в MySQL таблицу

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Использую preparedStatement, вот код:

```
query = "INSERT INTO instdb (" +
         "id," +
         "name," +
         "username," +
         "descr," +
         "tel," +
         "vk," +
         "ownerId," +
         "query," +
         "postId," +
         "parametr) VALUES" +
         "(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
stmt.setInt(1, maxid);
stmt.setString(2,user.getFull_name());
stmt.setString(3,username);
stmt.setString(4,caption);
stmt.setString(5,longestTel);
stmt.setString(6,vk);
stmt.setString(7,ownerId);
stmt.setString(8,addons.get(j));
stmt.setString(9,postId);
stmt.setString(10,param);
```

На строке `stmt.setInt(1, maxid);` появляется ошибка:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0)
```

Comment: @raviga Тогда расскажите Oracle об этом, они наверное тоже в примерах ошибаются

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html

Comment: а где строка инициализации stmt?

Answer (score 1):

Вы получите эту ошибку при вызове любого из setXxx()методов PreparedStatement, в то время как строка запроса SQL не имеет никаких заполнителей ?для этого.

```
Например, это неправильно :

String sql = "INSERT INTO tablename (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (val1, val2, val3)";
// ...

preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
preparedStatement.setString(1, val1); // Fail.
preparedStatement.setString(2, val2);
preparedStatement.setString(3, val3);
```

Вам необходимо исправить строку SQL-запроса соответствующим образом, чтобы указать заполнители.

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO tablename (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
// ...

preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
preparedStatement.setString(1, val1);
preparedStatement.setString(2, val2);
preparedStatement.setString(3, val3);
```

Обратите внимание, что индекс параметра начинается с того, что вам не нужно заключать в кавычки эти заполнители следующим образом:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO tablename (col1, col2, col3) VALUES ('?', '?', '?')";
```

В противном случае вы все равно получите то же исключение, потому что анализатор SQL будет интерпретировать их как фактические строковые значения и, следовательно, больше не сможет найти заполнители.

Comment: Простите, а каким это образом касается моего вопроса? И зачем копировать с английского stackoverflow ответ, если он не отвечает требованиям?

Comment: Если вы внимательно прочитаете свой код, и тот что в ответе вы найдете в чем у вас ошибка.